# Stopping a loop in my hp bar

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am in the process of making a game but i am having trouble with my Hp bar class that i am making for this game, using the code below:

```
import pygame, sys

class hpbar():
    def __init__(self, hpchunk, screen, posx, posy):
        # hpchunk can either be 125 or 250
        self.hpchunk = hpchunk
        self.screen = screen
        self.posx = posx
        self.posy = posy
        self.unit_h = 18
        self.unit_w = 250
        self.image = pygame.image.load('hpbar.png')
        self.total_hp = [self.posx + 3, self.posy + 3, self.unit_w, self.unit_h]  # +3 is there due to the thickness of the actual HP bar 
        self.val_per_chunk = self.unit_w / self.hpchunk                     # units of a single chunk e.g. 250 / 125 = 2
        self.startPos = 253
        screen.blit(self.image, [self.posx, self.posy])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 255, 0], self.total_hp, 0)

    def loss(self, loss_val):
        self.loss_val = loss_val
        total_chunk = self.loss_val * self.val_per_chunk                    
        chunkPosx = self.posx + self.startPos                               # e.g. if hpchunk = 125, then the hp will be in chunks of two
        healthbar = [0, 255, 0]
        chunkRangeEnd = self.unit_w - total_chunk                           
        total_chunk = 0                                                     # first iterative value
        stop_val = chunkPosx - total_chunk
        for lossx in range(self.unit_w, chunkRangeEnd, -self.val_per_chunk):
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, healthbar, self.total_hp, 0)      # hp bar 
            chunkPosx = chunkPosx - self.val_per_chunk                      # x position of chunk 
            total_chunk = total_chunk + self.val_per_chunk                  # total size of chunk
            if chunkPosx <= self.posx + 141:                                # yellow zone
                healthbar = [255, 255, 0]
            if chunkPosx <= self.posx + 48:                                 # red zone
                if self.val_per_chunk == 25:
                    healthbar = [255, 255, 255]
                else:
                    healthbar = [255, 0, 0]
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, [255, 0, 255], [chunkPosx, self.posy + 3, total_chunk, self.unit_h], 0)
            pygame.time.delay(200)
            pygame.display.flip()

    # chunkPosx = 253 + 150 = 403
    # total_chunk = 5 * 2 = 10
    # chunkRangeEnd = 250 - 20 = 230

    # chunkPosx iteration
    # x = x - 2
    # 403 = 403 - 2
    # 401 = 403 - 2     1st
    # 399 = 401 - 2     2nd
    # 397 = 399 - 2     3rd
    # 395 = 397 - 2     4th
    # 393 = 395 - 2     5th

    # total_chunk iteration
    # x = x + 2
    # 0 = 0 + 2
    # 2 = 0 + 2     1st 
    # 4 = 2 + 2     2nd
    # 6 = 4 + 2     3rd
    # 8 = 6 + 2     4th
    #10 = 8 + 2     5th 

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([720, 480])
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.flip()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    # test, using hp bar instance
    newbar = hpbar(125, screen, 150, 150)
    newbar.loss(5)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I wrote my module like this in order to make it re-usable in different areas of the game, Another thing to note is that an image and a series of rectanges are used to display hp.

Whenever i give a value to my loss method, it keeps iterating the same amount of chunks lost from the starting position; this is making it difficult for me to stack values deducted when i call a second or even third loss method after the previous, is there anyway i can stop this?
On another note, the chunks are there to animate the loss/gain over time, all displayed on my hp bar image; i tried using break statements in different areas of the code but they don't generate the output that's intended but instead it limits the overal chunk value lost

if you can help me, that will be much appreciated.
Thanks and apoligies if i didn't explain this correctly.

Comment: As an alternative to your current approach, I would suggest programming the bar to size only according to the ratio between current and max health of an entity.  You could do so using scale.  Your current implementation using 'chunks' of the bar seems overly-complex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what's not working.

I think you're drawing a HP bar, that shows **cur hp X%** .  Is the chunks to animate the loss over time? If so, pausing with delay there, will prevent the rest of your program from being able to update until it's done. Or is it to show chunks in the bar?

One way you could do it is like this:

```
class HpBar():
    def __init__(self, max_hp=56, cur_hp=20):
        self.max_hp = 56
        self.cur_hp = 20
        self.animating = False
        self.animate_delay = 200

    def damage(self, dmg):
        # damage and start animation
        self.cur_hp -= dmg
        self.started_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()        
        self.animating = True

    @property
    def ratio(self):
        # get ratio in the range [0., 1.] from original range [0, max_hp]
        return self.cur_hp * (1. / self.max_hp)

    def draw(self):
        # draw background max and current

        # start the same
        hp_box_max = Rect(...)
        hp_box_cur = Rect(hp_box_max)
        hp_box_animate = Rect(hp_box_max)
        hp_box_cur.width = self.ratio * hp_box_max.width

        # always show hp cur/max
        draw(hp_box_max)
        draw(hp_box_cur)

        # animation over?
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        elapsed = now - self.started_ticks
        if now - elapsed > self.animate_duration:
            self.animating = False

        # only show extra effect if animating
        if self.animating:
            hp_box_animate.left = hp_box_cur.right
            hp_box_animate.right = hp_box_cur.right

            # now animate based on time elapsed
            chunks = elapsed / self.animate_delay

            # if elapsed is 200, chunks = 1
            # elapsed 400, chunks = 2 , etc...
            hp_box_animate.width = chunks * chunk_width    
            draw(hp_box_animate)
```

`draw()` is recalculating the 3 rects, (or 2 if the animation finishes). If you wanted to, `cur_hp` can be upgraded to a `@property` which will auto-render and cache the updated surfaces. I use a similar method to cache rendering of text, and only re-render if the data causes the dirty bool to be set.